# Laravel 10 - Getting the env returns the entire .env file

Tags: php, laravel, phpdotenv

I have tried a few different ways to do this, but if I do `env("APP_ENV")` I get the entires contents of the env file instead of the APP_ENV value

I know this is bad practice but I also get the same results when using `Config`

I have tried `artisan cache:clear` and `artisan config:clear` and still the same results.

```
// dd(Config::get('env')); // this does the same 
dd(Config::get('app.APP_ENV'), Config::get('app.EMAILMODE'), env("APP_ENV"));
```

returns

```
"""
APP_NAME=Laravel


APP_ENV="local"


APP_KEY=*removed*


APP_DEBUG=true


APP_URL=*removed*



LOG_CHANNEL=stack


LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null


LOG_LEVEL=debug



DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv


DB_HOST=*removed*


DB_PORT=1433


DB_DATABASE=*removed*


DB_USERNAME=*removed*


DB_PASSWORD=*removed*


DB_ENCRYPT=true


DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE=true

""" // app/Http/Controllers/SecurityScanController.php:32

"testing" // app/Http/Controllers/SecurityScanController.php:32

"""
APP_NAME=Laravel


APP_ENV="local"


APP_KEY=*removed*


APP_DEBUG=true


APP_URL=*removed*



LOG_CHANNEL=stack


LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null


LOG_LEVEL=debug



DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv


DB_HOST=*removed*


DB_PORT=1433


DB_DATABASE=*removed*


DB_USERNAME=*removed*


DB_PASSWORD=*removed*


DB_ENCRYPT=true


DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE=true

""" // app/Http/Controllers/SecurityScanController.php:32
```

Comment: (Didn't downvote) That is definitely not the default behaviour... And I can't replicate this: [when I drop your code into a local test route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8crd.png) [I get the expected output of `null`, `null`, `'local'`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjkRo.png), since I don't have either `app.APP_ENV` or `app.EMAILMODE` set in `config/app.php`, and my env in not cached, so `env('APP_ENV')` returns `'local'` properly.

Comment: You'll probably need to include more debugging details; environment (windows, mac, etc.), how your running your project (`php artisan serve`, a webserver, docker, etc.).

Comment: It's not "bad practice" it just doesn't work in any reasonable production environment. Use the `config()` helper, and double check you haven't somehow messed up quotes or line endings.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments, I forgot to mention I also tried config() with the same issue.  The environment is happening within a docker container and on a windows server.  It is an upgraded app so I think something has gone wrong there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax to obtain from config file is the following:

```
config('app.env')
```

instead of `Config::get('app.APP_ENV')`
, where `app` refers to the file itself: `config\app.php` and the next string `env` refers to the key array on that file.

If you want to read directly from the env variables, the syntax is:

```
env('APP_ENV')
```

I would check for unclosed quotes in the .env file that may be invalidating it.  Also, when the value is a single word, you don't need to enclose it in quotes.

```
APP_ENV=local
```

works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the help on this.  I've eventually found out the originally code had an env file rotator.  the content of the env file would hold some text and the system would then use that text with the .env extension to load that specific file.  after removing all that all the above suggestions work.  I've marked Joe's answer as correct as it is technically correct but not the resolution for this.

If anyone else comes across a similar issue, for me in the `\bootstrap\app.php` file there was an include to an `environment.php` file in the same folder.  removing this include solved the issue and returned it back to expected outputs.